# How to disable a set of links in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a set of links in  tag

when a user clicks on one of the link the database takes time(3-5secs) to get the result page in this while the if the user clicks on other links it is getting redirected to other link.

how can we prevent or handle this situation?

Comment: Please include some more details and some code. Follow the guidelines on asking a good question here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `how can we prevent or handle this situation?` Write the program (code) or hire a coder (Programmer).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following class to all the links, till the time you are getting response. Then remove the classes once you got the result.

```
.noClick
{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```